# django-taggit - how do I display the tags related to each record

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-taggit

I'm using [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/) on one of my projects and I'm able to save and tie the tags with specific records. Now the question is how do I display the tags related to each record?

For example on my page I want to display a record which contains a title and content and then under it I want to show the tags tied to that record.

What goes in the views.py, and mytemplate.html? Real examples would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class MyObject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    tags = TaggableManager()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import simple

def show_object(request):
    """ View all objects """
    return simple.direct_to_template(request,
        template="folder/template.html",
        extra_context={
            'objects':MyObject.objects.all(),
        })
```

**template.html**

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <h2>{{ object.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ object.content }}</p>
    <ul>
        {% for tag in object.tags.all %}
            <li> {{ tag.name }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this will create an additional db query for each object that you have. if you have a lot of objects, that can really slow things down. I've run into that and am looking for a solution.

Comment: I'm a bit late replying @teewuane but yes you are right. It could be reduced by making use of `preselect_related` to prefetch the tags up front

Comment: `from django.views.generic import simple` is not working for me. Is this module deprecated ?

Answer (score 22):

If you are in a hurry you can also try:

```
{{context_name.tags.all|join:", "}}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.